# How to create push and pull mechanism using Servo

Tags: arduino, robotic-arm, kinematics, rcservo

How do I create a push and pull mechanism using a standard hobby servo? Eg. SG-5010

Preferably without the need of 3D printing.

Comment: Are you asking for mechanical structures to be used or fabrication methods?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Raven, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simply - suppose you want to push-pull a switch.

You fix the servo and the switch (or any other manipulateable object) to some base.

Then set the servo to center position, put the plastic cross/handle/other connecting element of servo in place such way, that its end point is in right angle to the switch (and fix it with a little screw to servo). The switch should be oriented such way, that it moves toward/from the end point.

Then connect the switch and the endpoint with some hard rod (you can use wood or some piece of hard plastics for this. Cut the right shape/lenght with sharp knive).

Then you loosely screw the rod to the endpoint of servo on one side and the switch (moved to central position) on other side.

then if you rotate the servo toward the switch, it is pushed away by the rod, if you rotate the servo on the othe side, the switch is pulled back.

(It is wonderfull how many mechanical pieces you can do fast with simple piece of wood and sharp knife. Much faster, that to print them in 3D (design included). I do a lot of parts from wood, usually I do not need to re-make them later, when the machine is finished, from any "better material", as the wood is good enought.)

Comment: I second this approach.  Many concepts have begun as balsa wood models.  Or even acrylic.

Comment: Woah thanks! Very much detailed explanation. Tho I'm having a hard time visualizing what you mean but I do get the point if how to use Servo's angle to make a push and pull.

Comment: If you have some illustrations or some projects you can share having this mechanism m - then sharing it would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I do not have exactly this, but (as a joke) I made something what can make you idea how 3D print is (not)necessary: on "OneWire conferency" I came with [http://robodoupe.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/P2030691_t.jpg] - it transfers info with one wire (literally, pulling it and counting time) as much complicated as I could do it - here is the servo part [http://robodoupe.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/P2030692_t.jpg] - just substitute that "one wire" with a wooden rod  - the rubber part to pull (and switchs spring to push) would be unnecessary. Main message - dont be scared of wood :)

Comment: Did it all over one afternoon and night, including all programming, just to have fun.